# A question about Voiculescu's theorem

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

[image]

I saw many reference books, when the authors state the theorem, they assume that the representation spaces $H$ and $K$ are separable.

My question : If the representation spaces are non-separable, does the theorem also hold?

Comment: Is this really true? What if $H = K = l^2$, $A = \mathbb{C}\cdot I \subset B(H)$ consists of the scalars, and we define $\phi(aI) = ap$ where $p$ is some rank 1 projection in $B(K)$. Then any isometry $V: K \to H$ will satisfy $V^*I_HV = I_K$, whose difference with $\phi(I) = p$ is not compact. Am I missing some hypotheses?

Comment: Can we assume that $H$ is non-separable and $K$ is separable?

Comment: Can you explain to my why what I said isn't a counterexample in both the separable and nonseparable settings? Is $A$ assumed to be irreducibly represented or something?

Comment: Accoring to the example you construct,,the theorem does not hold when $H$ and $K$ are non-separable. But I saw a conclusion from one paper : When $(\pi,H)$ is any representation of a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$,  $(\rho, \Bbb C^n)$ is finite dimentional irreducible representation of $A$, then by Voiculescu' s theorem, there exists a sequence of isometries $V_n：\Bbb C^n \rightarrow H$ such that ..... I was confused about the conclusion, if $H$ is non-separable, can we use the Voiculescu's theorem?

Comment: @NikWeaver: I am confused as well...  For reference, the image is from the book of Brown and Ozawa, and reference [53] is to Davidson's book.  I wonder if the CP is meant to be UCP?  (This is a hypothesis in a key Lemma Davidson uses; but the main proof is too dense, and it's too late in the evening, for me to be able to trace through what happens in your example.)

Comment: @Nik Weaver， I think $\varphi :A\rightarrow B(K)$ should be a non-degenerate representation.

Comment: Ugh. Thank you both very much for catching not one but two! (1) Both $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal K$ have to be separable; and (2) $\varphi$ has to be unital if $A$ is unital (or $V_k$'s are to be contractions rather than isometries). The proof of Theorem II.5.3 in Davidson's book assumes $P_n\varphi(\,\cdot\,)P_n$ is unital when it invokes Lemma II.5.2.

Comment: @Narutaka OZAWA， I saw a conclusion from Prof Brown's paper: Let $\phi：A\rightarrow B(H)$ be any representation of $A$ and $\rho:A\rightarrow B(\Bbb C^n)$ .If $\rho$ is weaked contained in $\pi$($ker(\pi)\subset ker(\rho)$), Then we can use Voiculsecu 's theroem to get a sequence of isometries $Vn：\Bbb C^n\rightarrow H$  such that... I was very congused about the conclusion. IF $H$ is non-separable, we cannot use the Voiculescu's theorem.

Comment: Indeed, one doesn't need separability of $\mathcal H$, for if $A\subset\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is separable, then one can find a separable $A$-invariant Hilbert subspace $\mathcal{H}_0\subset\mathcal{H}$ to which the restriction is faithful on $A$.

Comment: So in the above theroem we can take $H$ to be non-separable?